# D3 error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I know similar questions have been answered before, and I tried those before posting here. I am trying to build a Dendrogram but getting this error. I suppose it's unable to find the "children" but I don't understand why.

Below is my json. It's valid.

```
{
"name": "flare",
"children": [{
    "name": "Animals & Pet Supplies",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Live Animals"
    }, {
        "name": "Pet Supplies",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Bird Supplies",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Bird Cages & Stands"
            }, {
                "name": "Bird Food"
            }, {
                "name": "Bird Ladders & Perches"
            }, {
                "name": "Bird Toys"
            }, {
                "name": "Bird Treats"
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Cat Supplies"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

And below is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>-->
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
         .node circle {
         cursor: pointer;
         fill: #fff;
         stroke: steelblue;
         stroke-width: 1.5px;
         }
         .node text {
         font-size: 11px;
         }
         path.link {
         fill: none;
         stroke: #ccc;
         stroke-width: 1.5px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="body">
         <div id="footer">
            d3.layout.tree
            <div class="hint">click or option-click to expand or collapse</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
             w = 1280 - m[1] - m[3],
             h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
             i = 0,
             root;

         var tree = d3.layout.tree()
             .size([h, w]);

         var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
             .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

         var vis = d3.select("#body").append("svg:svg")
             .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
             .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
           .append("svg:g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

         d3.json("flare_orig_reduced.json", function(json) {
           root = json;
           root.x0 = h / 2;
           root.y0 = 0;

           function toggleAll(d) {
             if (d.children) {
               d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
               toggle(d);
             }
           }

           // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
           root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
           toggle(root.children[1]);
           toggle(root.children[1].children[2]);
           toggle(root.children[9]);
           toggle(root.children[9].children[0]);

           update(root);
         });

         function update(source) {
           var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

           // Compute the new tree layout.
           var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

           // Normalize for fixed-depth.
           nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

           // Update the nodes…
           var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
               .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

           // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
           var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "node")
               .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
               .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });

           nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
               .attr("r", 1e-6)
               .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

           nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
               .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
               .attr("dy", ".35em")
               .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
               .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
               .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

           // Transition nodes to their new position.
           var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

           nodeUpdate.select("circle")
               .attr("r", 4.5)
               .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

           nodeUpdate.select("text")
               .style("fill-opacity", 1);

           // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
           var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
               .remove();

           nodeExit.select("circle")
               .attr("r", 1e-6);

           nodeExit.select("text")
               .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

           // Update the links…
           var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
               .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

           // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
           link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
               .attr("class", "link")
               .attr("d", function(d) {
                 var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                 return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
               })
             .transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .attr("d", diagonal);

           // Transition links to their new position.
           link.transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .attr("d", diagonal);

           // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
           link.exit().transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .attr("d", function(d) {
                 var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                 return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
               })
               .remove();

           // Stash the old positions for transition.
           nodes.forEach(function(d) {
             d.x0 = d.x;
             d.y0 = d.y;
           });
         }

         // Toggle children.
         function toggle (d) {
           if (d.children) {
             d._children = d.children;
             d.children = null;
           } else {
             d.children = d._children;
             d._children = null;
           }
         }


      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to show all the nodes opened up initially.

You dont need to write a toggleAll function to open all the nodes, as they are open by default since all nodes have children.

So you can remove all this code:

```
  function toggleAll(d) {
     if (d.children) {
       d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
       toggle(d);
     }
   }

   // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
   root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
   toggle(root.children[1]);
   toggle(root.children[1].children[2]);
   toggle(root.children[9]);
   toggle(root.children[9].children[0]);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4dZN4isO9X8E5HVdcJxq?p=preview)

Comment: Works! Thanks! I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough points :/ Quick question - how would you approach if you don't want each node to have children, and don't edit the original json?

Comment: My mistake, the code will run with out the children as well http://plnkr.co/edit/4dZN4isO9X8E5HVdcJxq?p=preview it was the toggle all that was causing the error.

Comment: Great! I checked that. Thanks again.

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)